# Correct value type for function pointers in C

Tags: c, function-pointers

I was trying to understand function pointers in C. While reading about it on internet (mostly stack overflow QAs) - I came across 2 ways in which I can assign value to a function pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>

double add(int a, double b) {
  return a + b;
}

double subtract(int a, double b) {
  return a - b;
}

int main() {
  int op_a = 23;
  double op_b = 2.9;

  // Case 1. Just pass the function (not its address)
  double (*math_op)(int a, double b) = add;
  printf("The output of Math Operation %f\n", math_op(op_a, op_b));

  // Case 2. Pass the function's address
  math_op = &subtract;
  printf("The output of Math Operation %f\n", math_op(op_a, op_b));

  printf("End of program\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I have couple of questions

1. In the code above - what is the right way to assign value value to function pointer. I see several answers on stack overflow which follow the convention followed in *case 1*, and I also see some answers following convention in *case 2*. Both seem to be working correctly for me. Which is one is correct (or preferable)?
2. Also, in order to call function pointers I see 2 ways in which you can call them - `math_op(op_a, op_b)` or `(*math_op)(op_a, op_b)`. Again, is there a preferable way of doing this - both seem to be working correctly for me.

Comment: It doesn't matter, but I would suggest being consistent throughout your code with the method you do choose to go with, not mix and match

Comment: !Nishant Note: posted code lacks a declaration of `math_op` and a 1st case assignment.  Suggest adding these your post for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think

[Function calls (§6.5.2.2/1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.2.2):

> The expression that denotes the called function shall have type pointer to function returning void or returning an object type other than an array type.

is enough to answer both of your questions. The name of a function is implicitly converted to *pointer to function type* so using the address-of operator when assigning the adress of a function to a function pointer is superfluous. As for calling functions by function pointers the syntax is no different from "ordinary" function calls.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a quirk of C. The `*` and (a single) `&` are kind of ignored when taking an address of a function.

```
int main() {
    printf("%p %p %p", (void*)add, (void*)************add, (void*)&add);
}
```

The `*` are ignored when "dereferencing" a function pointer

```
int main() { 
    double (*math_op)(int a, double b) = add;
     printf("%p %p %f", (void*)math_op, (void*)*************math_op, (***************math_op)(1, 1.0));
}
```

It does not matter. However be consistent. Mostly I saw no `*` nor `&` used in such contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 is preferred.

The `&` is optional to take the address of a function (just like: `char buf[100]; char *bp = buf;`)

The reason case 1 is preferred is that the *syntax* is the *same* for assignment to a function pointer from a function *address* or another function *pointer*:

```
typedef double (*math_func)(int a, double b);
math_func math_op = add;
math_func math_op2 = sub;
math_func math_op3 = math_op2;
```

Analogously, that's why you can say: `math_op(2,23)` as a shorthand for: `(*math_op)(2,23)`

---

**UPDATE:**

> Pointer typedefs are not preferred (by me anyway)

They certainly help for function pointers [which Jonathan Leffler makes an exception for].

If you had (e.g.) 10 functions that needed to take an argument that was a function pointer, would you want to spell it out in all 10 function prototypes, particularly if the function pointer took 8 arguments itself?

Suppose [in some API] you had a function pointer:

```
typedef void (*funcptr)(int x,int y,int z);
```

Consider that you had functions of the form:

```
void func(funcptr f,...);
```

And, you had a call chain of these functions:

```
a -> b -> c -> d -> apiabc
```

Functions `a-d` do *not* call `f`--only `apiabc` does. Only `apiabc` has knowledge of how to call `f` properly. The others are merely passing along the *opaque* [to them] pointer so that `apiabc` can act on it.

If `funcptr` ever had to change, changing `a-d` would be problematic (i.e. they are *not* part of the API--merely users of it).

On pointer `typedef`s in general, IMO, they are fine *if* they are reasonably obvious and *consistent*.

This would be an example of usages:

```
typedef struct node *Node;              // poor
typedef struct node *pNode;             // MS (common but, IMO, poor)
typedef struct node *nodeP;             // okay
typedef struct node *nodeptr;           // better?
typedef const struct node *nodecptr;    // better?
```

IMO, the MS version is poor because if we sorted all names `pNode` would get intermixed with all [unrelated] `pWhatever` and not gravitate to `node` whereas looking left to right `nodeP` has the dominant part first (i.e. it's related to a node).

IMO, it is *hubris* for POSIX to lay claim to `whatever_t` as its province for type names. But, it's low probability that there will be a collision [for me, anyway, because I always use names that are likely to *not* conflict]. If there *is* a collision based on a *future* POSIX type, I lose, and have to change my definitions.

Thus, my personal conventions are:

```
typedef struct node node_t;
typedef node_t *node_p;
typedef const node_t *node_pc;
```

Any such convention can be used so long as it's applied consistently. In a given set of code, if one encounters `foo_p` for the first time, yes, one has to look in the `.h` file for the definition. After that, when one sees `bar_p`, the convention is already known.

For me, this usually isn't a problem, because when I encounter an unfamiliar code base, I always look at the definitions in the `.h` file *before* looking at code in a `.c`

Comment: Pointer typedefs are not preferred (by me anyway)

Comment: @M.M Granted, this is a bit of personal style/preference. I've added an update to my answer (too long for a comment) that lays out how I use pointer typedefs and why. See what you think ...

Comment: False dichotomy, you compare pointer typedef with not using typedef at all... I would use a non-pointer typedef. `typedef double math_func(int a, double b);  math_func add, sub;  /* ... */ math_func *math_op = add;`.  Later on you recommend `node_p` with the comment "one has to look in the .h file for the definition". However if you just used `node_t *` then nothing needs to be looked up